# How to use pip to install lxml in different version of python?

Tags: python, lxml, pip

In my os, `/usr/bin/python` is python2.6, and `/usr/local/bin/python` is python2.7.
I have installed pip, however, when I use the command:

```
pip install lxml
```

I found I can use lxml in python2.7, but I can't use it in python2.6

```
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

How can I install lxml in python2.6 with pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `pip` executable is for one Python version/install, and it can tell you which. On my system:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

You may also have symlinks such as `pip-2.7` for a particular version.

In your case, if you don’t have it already, you need first to install pip in Python 2.6. Depending on you OS it might be better to install it with the distribution’s packages, or to install it through [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) (aka. `easy_install`)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to explicitly use the version of pip installed in 2.6:

```
$ /usr/bin/python/bin/pip install lxml
```

When you just run:

```
$ pip install lxml
```

the shell finds pip in `/usr/local/bin/python/bin` first and executes it - if you need to reference another one you need to either use the full path or modify your `PATH` environmental variable before running the command.